# A better way of saying collecting donations

Tags: synonyms, terminology, formality, politeness

I'm trying to find the nicest and most respectful way of saying: "collecting donations". 
After research, I've seen: "obtaining donations" or "collecting donations", or "getting donations".

In addition to being respectful, I am trying to convey that we collect these donations after cultivating them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say something like, "our foundation was graciously supported by the generous donations of benefactors to the tune of $xxx. These donations will be put to good use doing..."

or

"we were fortunate to receive the support from the community in the form of $xxx in donations" or"we were fortunate enough to receive donations..."

I feel "receive" is better because it is passive, whereas "collect" or "seek" is about the act of getting the money. I feel the tense makes a big difference to the context. Your question indicated present tense, but your comments indicated past tense, hence the answer provided.

Comment: I think that "receive" as mentioned by Alan is the best option since as pointed out is passive "whereas collect or seek is about the act of getting the money" and  "the tense [made] a big difference to the context"